# Fetch a variable set within a transaction

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, timestamp

I have a piece of java code that connects to a SQL Server that does something like the following:

First a bunch of batch through stmt.addBatch

```
declare @crt_dt as datetime
set @crt_dt = (select getdate())

update a_table set the_timestamp=@crt_dt
```

Then a select using `stmt.executeQuery`

```
select @crt_dt as my_timestamp
```

Then `stmt.executeBatch`

Then `conn.commit`

The problem I have is that I got an error on select execution.  What did I do wrong?  Or is there an alternative to get the value `@crt_dt` out?

Also, if I don't have select, everything is all fine, except that I got a return int array with the values `-2`, `1`, `-3`. I don't understand where `-3` came from.

Comment: Also, if I don't have select, everything is all fine, except that I got a return int array with the values -2, 1, -3.  I don't understand where -3 came from.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you cannot run the `stmt.executeQuery` inside the context of the batch, or that you have to run the `stmt.executeBatch` before the `stmt.executeQuery`.

Can you just add the `select @crt_dt as my_timestamp` to the batch? In other words, can you return values from the batch?

Comment: how do i get the value from the select if i put it in batch?  the execute batch just returns a bunch of int codes.

Comment: I looked up the command (I'm not a Java guy) and I see that you cannot return a result set when you call stmt.executeBatch. I think you need to put all the code in one stmt.executeQuery command or put all the code in a stored procedure and use stmt.executeQuery to run the commands and return the result set.

Comment: The way it works is that the sql is generated in difference parts of the code.  Besides, the executeQuery call on each sql will cause @crt_dt not declared error in subsequent call.